# Communication between EJB and Flash possible?

Tags: java, flash

Is it possible to call my ejbs from Flash actionscript? If yes, can anybody give me any link or example to accomplish the same?

Also if my ejbs are returning List how will flash come to know about this class?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the EJB 3.1 standard, EJB methods can very easily be [exposed as REST services](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_13) that return JSON or XML data:

```
@GET
@Path("{orderid}/")
@Produces({"application/xml","application/json"})
public Order status(@PathParam("orderid") long orderId){
   return delivery.status(orderId);
}
```

Comment: great! exposing ejbs as restful web services.

Answer (score 1):

You need a communication layer in between the two:

BlazeDS http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/blazeds/BlazeDS/

or

GraniteDS http://www.graniteds.org/